# Rails - validate Float type when it's still a String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have **User** model with **:balance** field (it is **float** type). I want to write my own validation for this field, but i want to get access to this value when it's still a string and Rails didn't yet converted it to the float. I mean, i want to do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_balance

  def check_balance
    if balance.is_a?(String)
      # do my validation, add errors and etc.
    end
  end
end
```

How can i do that?

P.S. **validates_format_of** is not answer in my current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`<attribute>_before_type_cast`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Accessing+attributes+before+they+have+been+typecasted) returns the original value for `attribute`:

```
def check_balance
  if balance_before_type_cast.is_a?(String)
    // do my validation, add errors and etc.
  end
end
```